# Pull data from cm commerce using x-api-key

Tags: python, python-requests, campaign-monitor

i am trying to pull data by referencing this [guide.](https://developers.commerce.campaignmonitor.com/#authentication)
I'm a little new. can i just pull data with api key and url. Because i have only api key and url. I don't have any of the other parameters. Here are the ways i tried:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = "https://commerce.campaignmonitor.com/api/v1/abandoned-carts/campaigns"
header={"x-api-key" : 'my_api_key'}
post_param = urllib.parse.urlencode({
                    'user' : 'i_dont_know',
           'status-update' : 'i_dont_know'
          }).encode('UTF-8')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, post_param, header)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

and this:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import urllib

url ="https://commerce.campaignmonitor.com/api/v1/abandoned-carts/campaigns"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('my_api_key', 'i_dont_know')

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers , auth=auth)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

but i have error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'type'
```

in other methods, I get 401 error

Comment: What do you print?

Comment: normally List Abandoned Cart Campaigns. actually i can do this with shell script but i can not do this in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python-requests` alone can do this for you (no need for `urllib`).
You have the `API key` so you shouldn't use the `HTTPBasicAuth`

this should work for you:

```
import requests

url ="https://commerce.campaignmonitor.com/api/v1/abandoned-carts/campaigns"

# like the doc says, provide API key in header
headers = {"Accept": "application/json",
'X-ApiKey': 'my_api_key'}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(req.json())
```

Comment: It took me days to find this thank you very much.